# TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoskin, dhtmlx-scheduler

I'm building a node js application with the DHTMLX Scheduler as one of the pages. However, whenver the page loads, the app crashes and I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at EventEmitter.(/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/collection.js:52:21))

Here is the module the error references:

```
  SkinCollection.prototype._open = function(callback) {
    var collection_args = this._collection_args.concat([callback]);
    this._skin_db.open(function(err, db) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        db.collection.apply(db, collection_args);
    });
  }
```

And here is the portion of my app.js that is causing the error, when I don't include this code the calendar doesn't crash the app but I have no way of sending the data to my MongoDB atlas cluster.

app.js

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.get('/init', function(req, res){
        db.event.insert({ 
            text:"My test event A", 
            start_date: new Date(2018,8,1),
            end_date:   new Date(2018,8,5)
        });
        db.event.insert({ 
            text:"My test event B", 
            start_date: new Date(2018,8,19),
            end_date:   new Date(2018,8,24)
        });
        db.event.insert({ 
            text:"Morning event", 
            start_date: new Date(2018,8,4,4,0),
            end_date:   new Date(2018,8,4,14,0)
        });
        db.event.insert({ 
            text:"One more test event", 
            start_date: new Date(2018,8,3),
            end_date:   new Date(2018,8,8),
            color: "#DD8616"
        });

        res.send("Test events were added to the database")
    });


    app.get('/data', function(req, res){
        db.event.find().toArray(function(err, data){
            //set id property for all records
            console.log(err);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                data[i].id = data[i]._id;

            //output response
            res.send(data);
        });
    });


    app.post('/data', function(req, res){
        var data = req.body;
        var mode = data["!nativeeditor_status"];
        var sid = data.id;
        var tid = sid;

        delete data.id;
        delete data.gr_id;
        delete data["!nativeeditor_status"];


        function update_response(err, result){
            if (err)
                mode = "error";
            else if (mode == "inserted")
                tid = data._id;

            res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            res.send({action: mode, sid: sid, tid: tid});
        }

        if (mode == "updated")
            db.event.updateById( sid, data, update_response);
        else if (mode == "inserted")
            db.event.insert(data, update_response);
        else if (mode == "deleted")
            db.event.removeById( sid, update_response);
        else
            res.send("Not supported operation");
    });
```

I've only been learning javascript for the past week and am very new to coding. I don't understand why this error is occuring. When I run the Scheduler app as a stand alone feature it works flawlessly. Only when I try to implement it in my website does it throw this error.

Comment: seems to me that your returned db object doesnt have the property `collection`.

Comment: How can I fix that.  Here is my db declaration:  `var db = require('mongoskin').db("linkToMyCluster", { w: 0});
 db.bind('event');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Correct Answer**

This question is a duplicate of: [MongoSkin "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900890/mongoskin-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined)

Mongoskin only supports MongoDB 2.x, this error happens when using MondoDB 3.x.

**Original (Incorrect) Answer**

Pretty new to MongoDB myself, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that you need to replace `collection` with the actual name of the table on this line:

```
db.collection.apply(db, collection_args);
```

So for example, if name of the table/collection was `skin`, the line would become:

```
db.skin.apply(db, collection_args);
```

(Notice how when `app.j` executes a db operation on the events table, it is calling `db.event.insert()`, etc...)

Comment: I already tried changing the collection.js file to `db.event.apply` (as my collection is named event) but it still throws the exact same error

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that the error was coming from a third-party module not your code.

It looks like this question may a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900890/mongoskin-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined, try checking and see if you have the same version conflict that this user did.

Comment: Thank you. It was a versioning issue. I don't know how that question didn't come up in my searches, I must've not looked hard enough :P